# Sendgrid API giving

Tags: .net

I am using Sendgrid API to send email but its showing error "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." and in catch block result giving message "{"errors":["Bad username / password"],"message":"error"}". I am using below code :-

```
        string api_user = "apiuser";
        string api_key = "Key";
        string toAddress = "test@test.com";
        string toName = "To Name";
        string subject = "A message from SendGrid";
        string text = "Delivered by your friends at SendGrid.";
        string fromAddress = "from@example.com";

        string url = "https://sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json";

        // Create a form encoded string for the request body
        string parameters = "api_user=" + api_user + "&api_key=" + api_key + "&to=" + toAddress + 
                            "&toname=" + toName + "&subject=" + subject + "&text=" + text +
                            "&from=" + fromAddress;

        try
        {
            //Create Request
            HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            myHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            //myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";

            // Create a new write stream for the POST body
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());

            // Write the parameters to the stream
            streamWriter.Write(parameters);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

            // Get the response
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            // Create a new read stream for the response body and read it
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            // Write the results to the console
            //Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            // Catch any execptions and gather the response
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;

            // Create a new read stream for the exception body and read it
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            return result;
            // Write the results to the console
            //Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Uri.EscapeDataString` for parameters

Example

```
var parameters = "api_user=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(api_user) 
                    + "&api_key=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(api_key) + //more values
```

Edit:

Also you can try to convert your `parameters` into byte array:

```
byte[] parametersData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters);
// Write the parameters to the stream
streamWriter.Write(parametersData);
```